# Webpack different names for entries

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

How i can specify different `filename` for different entry output?

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
  entry: {
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'lodash', 'redux'],
    app: './src/app.js'
  }
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, (isDevelopment) ? 'demo' : 'build'),
    filename: (isDevelopment) ? '[name].js' : '[name][chunkhash:12].js'
  }
}
```

To receive output like this

```
build
-- index.html
-- app.2394035ufas0ue34.js
-- vendor.js
```

So browser will cache `vendor.js` with all libraries. Since i don't plan to migrate to any major new release anytime soon and often.
And still being able to break cache for `app.js` with every update required.

is there some kind of option to set `output` as

```
output: {
  app: {
    ...
  },
  vendor: {
    ...
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
  entry: {
    './build/app': './src/app.js',
    './build/vendor': VENDOR_LIBS // or path to your vendor.js
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
```

Add this code into your webpack `plugins` array as last element of an array.

```
plugins: [
 ... // place our new plugin here
]

function() {
  this.plugin("done", function(stats) {
    const buildDir = __dirname + '/build/';
    const fs = require('fs');
    var vendorTempFileName = '';

    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      fs.readdir(buildDir, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {

        if (file.substr(0,6) === 'vendor') {
          resolve(file);
        }

        });
      });
    }).then(function(file) {

      fs.rename( buildDir + file, buildDir + 'vendor.js', function(err) {
        if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
      });

    });

  });
}
```

Output should be as follows: 
[image]

It is considered bad practice to leave your files without chunkhashes, due to browser caching.

Comment: This is still not resolves my different naming problem. I need to set
`vendor.js` as `[name].js`
and
`app.js` as `[name].[chunkhash].js`

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Should work as you wanted, I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

For Webpack 4 I added a quick-and-dirty `done` hook to rename my service worker script:

```
  // Plugin to rename sw-[chunkhash].js back to sw.js
  class SwNamePlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
      compiler.hooks.done.tap("SW Name Plugin", (stats) => {
        const swChunk = stats.compilation.chunks.find((c) => c.name === "sw");
        fs.rename(path.resolve(outDir, swChunk.files[0]), `${outDir}/sw.js`);
      });
    }
  }
  plugins.push(new SwNamePlugin());
```

This obviates the warning `DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on .hooks instead` you'd see following loelsonk's answer.